# Why does difference in name attribute of an HTML element affect variable value in a Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to learn Servlets and I came across an issue. When I use dashes or underscores in name attribute of an HTML element the value that servlet receives is null. However, If I don't use underscores or dashes, the servlet receives the entered value.

```
<input type="text" name="labourUnionFee" id="labour-union-fee" value="0">
String labourUnionFee = request.getParameter("labourUnionFee");
```

works fine and the result can be seen from here [output of the first snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd4ki.png), whereas

```
<input type="text" name="labour-union-fee" id="labour-union-fee" value="0">
String labourUnionFee = request.getParameter("labour-union-fee");
```

does not return any value when 'submit' button is pressed as this picture demonstrates [output of the second snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvU4W.png)

Why does this occur?

**EDIT**

I probably should have mentioned that I am also using an AJAX function:

```
function getNetSalary() {
        $("#submitButton").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                        url:'someservlet',
                        data: {
                            labourUnionFee: $('#labour-union-fee').val()
                        },
                        type: 'POST',
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data){
                            $('#net-salary-information-div').text(data);
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            alert('Please Fill all necessary fields');
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        );
```

And this is inside my 'someservlet':

```
String labourUnionFee = request.getParameter("labour-union-fee");
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(labourUnionFee);
```

Comment: Did you rebuild? Does the URL look correct when you submit this form? Showing us a portion of your webpage does nothing to help.

Comment: That should work as well .Maybe problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, yes, I did rebuild. It is a very simple webpage, therefore, I did not feel the need for posting the entire webpage. In any case, https://imgur.com/a/hWElSXB here it is. There are no URL problems, as when I change the name attribute everything works as it should be.

Comment: If everything works as it should **what** is your question?

Comment: So you didn't rename the field here `labourUnionFee: $('#labour-union-fee').val()` - ***guess*** what `labourUnionFee` does.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch , okay I think I got you now. Thanks.